# Redmine: Any advantage to Categories over Custom Fields?

Tags: redmine

I am evaluating Redmine, and I wonder if there is any advantage to Categories over Custom Fields?

Indeed, Categories can't be shared between projects so far and it's a strong drawback for me.

I have the feelings categories are only useful if one needs different categories between projects.
In other words, it's a project property instead of a tracker property like custom fields.

I am missing something here?

Thanks you!

Comment: Redmine is flexible project management solution. If you organize your projects in parent-child fashion you can inherit categories and stuff...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately, inheritance is usually not the best way to cope with this kind of issues. I think I'll try not to use them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Redmine, Category is a standard field used by trackers and has different values defined for each project in the project 'configuration' tab.
Category values **cannot** be shared nor inherited in Redmine projects.
This is some serious drawback which is [discussed by the community](http://www.redmine.org/issues/11898). A patch is available to customize Redmine, but it targets an old version of the application.

An alternate solution is to create a custom field, say Cat, which would be used as a category. That Cat field can be used by any project with any tracker.
It also means that the Cat values are shared for all projects which can be pointless if you have a 'cooking' and a 'mechanics' projects...

There are two solutions to deal with it :

- Create a Cat custom field for each project, but the name of the custom field has to be unique
- Use the [Custom Values Per Project plugin](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_custom_values_per_project) to limit available Cat values for each project, which can be a pain i you have lots of projects
- You can even possibly use a combination of those two !

That is the only solution I have found so far.

Comment: Thanks. I reached the same conclusion :).